# Communication between web application and desktop application

Tags: web-services, web-applications, jsf-2, desktop-application

*Is it possible to call a deskop application(executable jar) from web application. assume i have an jsf web application and java swing application(calculator). can i call calculator app from my jsf web applicaton that run on server.*